# Asp.net MVC eCommerce app - Add To Cart implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

Let say I am rendering list of products with *Add To Cart* link / button next to each.

I also have a **CartController** with **AddToCart** Action that accept a parameter of **Product** type.

After product is added to cart user should stay on the same page (Product list) - not to be redirected to Cart or something.

I am rendering Cart summary partial view that should update itself.

So my question is about implementation of the *Add To Cart* link / button.

Should I use: **Html.ActionLink(...)**

or **Html.BeginForm()** and  Submit button.

Maybe there is other ways...

How do I send Product info in each case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is to have a form for each add button (with maybe the quantity also), since you want your AddToCart action only receive POST actions anyway, that way you process all the add to cart logic and then redirect to your main catalog view (or something like that :)

Comment: I am going to implement this method for now and probably will add js/jQuery on later stages.
Thanks everyone for input

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a [jQuery.post()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) request to your CartController.AddToCart.  Make AddToCart a partial view.  And then show a modal popup (div on top of your page) that shows that the product was added to the cart...then do a fade out!

Keep it simple.

Now keep in mind that some of your users won't be able to support jquery/javascript.  So make the initial add to cart button post to an add to cart page (not partial page..full page)...which can return them to the original page.  Then spot weld your jquery function on top of the add to cart button.  This way you cover both worlds nicely.

Take a look at the concept of unobtrusive javascript/jquery.

Comment: Can get be cached by Google and such?  I remember reading something about this and how Google had cached a delete command that used get instead of post.  Not sure it applies to this situation though.

Comment: You can perform a post on it if you prefer.  A link can indeed get cached but you could add it to your no robots list so they don't look at it.  You can check the referrer on that page to make sure that it comes from your site.  There are a lot of ways around that.  But that doesn't really matter because google will only be acting on it's own behalf.

Comment: Actually it could be a problem if you do your "acting" actions (ie addToCart, RemoveFromCart, etc.) using get verbs, precisely because search bots could be generating carts and making a mess on your site without knowing (robots.txt is not the way to prevent this)... get should never change state on your data (ie multiple get commands should return the same result)

Answer (score 1):

Again I'd take into consideration what happens if the user doesn't have javascript. It's not very likely these days, but *do you want to lose a sale just because someone accidently turned off javascript*?

So what I'd do is create the somewhat typical AddToCart link (<a class="add" href="/Shop/AddToCart/5">). The AddToCart controller would then do it's stuff and redirect back to the product listing page (you might have to pass a parameter to specify which page to go back to).

So that's the first step to consider -- javascript turned off. Now you can think about how to do it with javascript.

Capture the click event ( *$('a.add').click(...)* ) and then you can do two things. One would be to call the URL (you can get it out of the event object) and then separately update the cart. You can also add a parameter to the URL so that it displays the cart partial view, doing something like (written from memory):

```
$('a.add').click(function(event) { $('#cart').load(event.target.attr('href') + '&showcart=1');
```

James

Comment: Performing an action (add, update, delete ) on a get request is not a good idea. Google might fill a very large shopping cart. But I guess your post was more about the unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: Good point. Though, unless proven otherwise, I personally wouldn't worry about it so much for a shopping cart, that hopefully has some sort of cleanup routine behind it. Fully agree with other sorts of adding and deleting though. And, yes to the unobtrusive js.